# After installing the cx recipe in SAP Commerce, execution error unable to install/path/npm/where

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

After installing the `cx` recipe in SAP Commerce, I tried to execute `ant clean all` but getting following error:

> Error: Unable to install package: Error: Unable to determine the path to the NPM tool: Error: Command failed: where npm 'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

[image]

`ant clean all` should be executed and build should be successful.

Detailed log:

```
alization-search\\personalizationsearchsmartedit,C:\\Users\\Trainee\\Desktop\\reciepe\\SAP-Commerce-2211-Patch-5\\hybris\\bin\\modules\\personalization-promotion\\personalizationpromotionssmartedit,',
     [exec]   'C:\\Users\\Trainee\\Desktop\\reciepe\\SAP-Commerce-2211-Patch-5\\hybris\\bin\\modules\\smartedit\\smartedittools',
     [exec]   'true'
     [exec] ]
     [exec] Adding npm dependencies to application, path: C:\Users\Trainee\Desktop\reciepe\SAP-Commerce-2211-Patch-5\hybris\bin\modules\smartedit\smartedit\apps\smartedit-master
     [exec] Dependencies:
     [exec] [
     [exec]   { name: 'personalizationcommons', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   { name: 'personalizationsmartedit', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   { name: 'personalizationsmarteditcontainer', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   { name: 'merchandisingsmartedit', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   { name: 'merchandisingsmarteditcommons', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   { name: 'merchandisingsmarteditcontainer', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   { name: '@smart/utils', version: '1.1.52' },
     [exec]   { name: 'smartedit', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   { name: 'smarteditbootstrap', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   { name: 'smarteditcommons', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   { name: 'smarteditcontainer', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   { name: 'smarteditloader', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   { name: 'webappinjector', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   { name: 'personalizationsearchsmartedit', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   { name: 'personalizationsearchsmarteditcontainer', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   { name: 'personalizationpromotionssmartedit', version: '0.0.1' },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     name: 'personalizationpromotionssmarteditcommons',
     [exec]     version: '0.0.1'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     name: 'personalizationpromotionssmarteditcontainer',
     [exec]     version: '0.0.1'
     [exec]   }
     [exec] ]
     [exec] ****** rush projects ******
     [exec] [
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: '@smartedit/packagr',
     [exec]     projectFolder: 'apps/smartedit-packagr'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: '@smartedit/scripts',
     [exec]     projectFolder: 'apps/smartedit-scripts'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'smartedit-build',
     [exec]     projectFolder: 'apps/smartedit-build'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: '@smart/utils',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\smartedit\\apps\\smart-utils'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'smarteditcommons',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\smartedit\\apps\\smartedit-commons'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'personalizationcommons',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\..\\personalization\\personalizationsmartedit\\apps\\personalizationcommons'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'smartedit',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\smartedit\\apps\\smartedit'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'personalizationsmartedit',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\..\\personalization\\personalizationsmartedit\\apps\\personalizationsmartedit'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'smarteditcontainer',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\smartedit\\apps\\smartedit-container'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'personalizationsmarteditcontainer',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\..\\personalization\\personalizationsmartedit\\apps\\personalizationsmarteditcontainer'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'merchandisingsmarteditcommons',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\..\\cds-merchandising\\merchandisingsmartedit\\apps\\merchandisingsmarteditcommons'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'merchandisingsmartedit',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\..\\cds-merchandising\\merchandisingsmartedit\\apps\\merchandisingsmartedit'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'merchandisingsmarteditcontainer',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\..\\cds-merchandising\\merchandisingsmartedit\\apps\\merchandisingsmarteditContainer'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'smarteditbootstrap',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\smartedit\\apps\\smartedit-bootstrap'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'smarteditloader',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\smartedit\\apps\\smartedit-loader'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'webappinjector',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\smartedit\\apps\\web-app-injector'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'personalizationsearchsmartedit',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\..\\personalization-search\\personalizationsearchsmartedit\\apps\\personalizationsearchsmartedit'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'personalizationsearchsmarteditcontainer',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\..\\personalization-search\\personalizationsearchsmartedit\\apps\\personalizationsearchsmarteditContainer'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'personalizationpromotionssmartedit',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\..\\personalization-promotion\\personalizationpromotionssmartedit\\apps\\personalizationpromotionssmartedit'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'personalizationpromotionssmarteditcommons',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\..\\personalization-promotion\\personalizationpromotionssmartedit\\apps\\personalizationpromotionssmarteditcommons'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'personalizationpromotionssmarteditcontainer',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\..\\personalization-promotion\\personalizationpromotionssmartedit\\apps\\personalizationpromotionssmarteditContainer'
     [exec]   },
     [exec]   {
     [exec]     packageName: 'smarteditmaster',
     [exec]     projectFolder: '..\\smartedit\\apps\\smartedit-master'
     [exec]   }
     [exec] ]
     [echo] check verdaccio.cache: C:\Users\Trainee\Desktop\reciepe\SAP-Commerce-2211-Patch-5\hybris\bin\modules\npm-ancillary\npmancillary\resources\npm\verdaccio\.cache
     [echo] verdaccio.cache is set to: false
     [echo] Running [rush update --bypass-policy] on path C:\Users\Trainee\Desktop\reciepe\SAP-Commerce-2211-Patch-5\hybris\bin\modules\smartedit\smartedittools
     [exec] The rush.json configuration requests Rush version 5.93.1
     [exec] Transforming C:\Users\Trainee\Desktop\reciepe\SAP-Commerce-2211-Patch-5\hybris\bin\modules\smartedit\smartedittools\common\config\rush\.npmrc
     [exec]   --> "C:\Users\Trainee\Desktop\reciepe\SAP-Commerce-2211-Patch-5\hybris\bin\modules\smartedit\smartedittools\common\temp\install-run\@microsoft+rush@5.93.1\.npmrc"
     [exec] Installing @microsoft/rush...
     [exec]
     [exec]
     [exec] Error: Unable to install package: Error: Unable to determine the path to the NPM tool: Error: Command failed: where npm
     [exec] 'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
     [exec] operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Are you using any sort of proxy? If that's the case you need to add export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path/to/custom/certificates/RootCA.crt to ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at the solutions in this link.
https://answers.sap.com/questions/13510712/rush-cannot-run-correctly-after-sap-commerce-upgra.html